# how to access serial port using c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to ask is there a library or assembly to access seral port to write on it using c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class in the Framework.  No extra library is required, since this is included in the System.dll assembly.